# Sending SMS-COMMAND PDU to SMSC for deleting submitted message

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, pdu

I am trying to send SMS-COMMAND PDU which should delete previously submitted message in SMSC. The modem is responding with +CMS 500 error which means invalid PDU mode.

the setup i am using 
- huawei modem

- AT+CMGF=0
- AT+CMGS=14

with PDU in bytes

> 00220000029E0C9124917091558500

the message number is set for the reference number previously submitted message.

modem is responding with +CMS 500. I cannot make this work so any advice would be appreciated. Thank you